# Reflection/Linq: Find class inside another in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, reflection

I have the next class in my code:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public Class MyDictionary 
        Public Shared Property something As String = "xxxxx"
        ...
    End Class

    Public Property dbId As Integer 
    Public Property dbDescription As String
    Public Property Activate As Boolean
    ...


End Class
```

What I am trying to do is to look for propertyInfo of MyDictionary class using Linq.

I tried to use

```
Dim propertyInfo = typeDest.GetProperty("MyDictionary", BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance)
```

But is returning me Nothing.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: `MyDictionary` isn't a property. It's a class. You can't find it with `GetProperty`.

Comment: I should spicify that properties inside mydictionary are SHARED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyDictionary` isn't a property. It's a class. You can't find it with `GetProperty`.

You'd have to do something like this:

```
Dim myDictionaryType As Type = _
    GetType([MyClass]) _
        .Assembly _
        .GetTypes() _
        .Where(Function(x) x.FullName.StartsWith(GetType([MyClass]).FullName)) _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Name = "MyDictionary")
        .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: not working ... I should spicify that properties inside mydictionary are SHARED